# Vuetify nested items props: How to show parent item id within nested component?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a v-virtual-scroll nested in a v-data-table like:

```
<v-data-table :items="itemsArray1">
    (...)
    <v-virtual-scroll :items="itemsArray2">
        (...)
        {{item.id}} this is the item id from itemsArray2 element
    </v-virtual-scroll>
</v-data-table>
```

Both has its own 'items' props.

PROBLEM: {{item.id}} inside v-virtual-scroll returns the itemArray2 element id. I want to access the itemArray1 element id.

QUESTION:
How to access the v-data-table item ID inside the nested v-virtual-scroll component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access scoped slots from `<v-data-table>`.
Something like this should work (see https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#item)

```
<v-data-table :items="itemsArray1">
    <template v-slot:item="{ item: itemArr1 }">
      <v-virtual-scroll :items="itemsArray2">
        (...)
        {{ itemArr1 }} // item from itemsArray1
        {{item.id}} // this is the item id from itemsArray2 element
      </v-virtual-scroll>
    </template> 
</v-data-table>
```